# How to change the column values in pandas based on some condition

Tags: python, pandas

I want to change the column values in a dataframe to another name when it matches some certain conditions.

I tried apply method on the dataframe but it didnt work.

This is the dataset i have and i want the country column names should be changed on some condition. For example "Republic of Korea" should be change to 'South Korea' and I have similar names that needs to be changed in this column. I tried apply method and i'm not getting any results. Any suggestions would help me. Thank you in advance.
**

```
df.head()

       Country Energy_Supply Energy_Supply_per_Capita   
0      Afghanistan      3.210000e       10.0    
1      Albania          1.020000e       35.0    
2      Algeria          1.959000e+09    51.0    
3      American Samoa   NaN             NaN
```

Comment: " i want the country column names should be changed on some condition" - there should be either a dictionary or please share the condition

Comment: Names on the left side is in the column  and names on the right side is the name that needs to be changed.                                                            
 "Republic of Korea": "South Korea",
"United States of America": "United States",
"United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland": "United Kingdom",
"China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region": "Hong Kong"

Comment: `df['Country'].map(dictionary_name)` should do it

Comment: Didnt work. All values in my dataframe changed to nan values.

Comment: can you post the dictionary you have in the question(based on the input dataframe you provided) if there are no trailing spaces, this should work

Comment: Will try another time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) for your column of interest.
Create a dictionary `repl_dict = {"Republic of China": "China", "Republic of Moldova": "Moldova", "Republic of France": "France","Great Britain": "England"}` and then pass is to replace function, for more details and parameters check [pandas.DataFrame.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

> This method does replace all at once by creating the `dictionary` with
>   all the names of interest, ultimately will standardize your
>   `dataframe` `column` based on this dictionary and no need to run
>   individually for each `Country`.

```
import pandas as pd
my_dict = { 'Country' : ["Republic of China", "China", "England", "Republic of Moldova", "Republic of France","Great Britain", "England"],
                   'age' : [20,27, 35, 55, 18, 21, 35],
                   'designation': ["VP", "CEO", "CFO", "VP", "VP", "CEO", "MD"]}

dfnew = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
print(dfnew)

Country  age designation
0    Republic of China   20          VP
1                China   27         CEO
2              England   35         CFO
3  Republic of Moldova   55          VP
4   Republic of France   18          VP
5        Great Britain   21         CEO
6              England   35          MD
```

> ```
> repl_dict = {"Republic of China": "China", "Republic of Moldova": "Moldova", "Republic of France": "France","Great Britain": "England"}
> dfnew['Country'] = dfnew['Country'].replace(repl_dict, regex=True)
> print()
> print('Final dataframe', dfnew)
> ```

```
Final dataframe    
Country  age designation
0    China   20          VP
1    China   27         CEO
2  England   35         CFO
3  Moldova   55          VP
4   France   18          VP
5  England   21         CEO
6  England   35          MD
```

Comment: Thats an impressive method. I dont know why I didnt try this method. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Why replace did not work? it seems that it is the good way:

```
df.head()

       Country Energy_Supply Energy_Supply_per_Capita   
0      Republic of Korea      3.210000e       10.0    
1      Albania          1.020000e       35.0    
2      Algeria          1.959000e+09    51.0    
3      American Samoa   NaN             NaN



df.replace({'Country': 'Republic of Korea'}, {'Country': 'South Korea'})

       Country Energy_Supply Energy_Supply_per_Capita   
0      South Korea      3.210000e       10.0    
1      Albania          1.020000e       35.0    
2      Algeria          1.959000e+09    51.0    
3      American Samoa   NaN             NaN
```

You can do this things several times. For each replace

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is the map function:

```
df['Country']= df['Country'].map(lambda x: 'South Korea' if x == 'Republic of Korea' else x)
```

The above expression is taking an element from df['Country'] and calling it x. If x == 'Republic of Korea' it is placing 'South Korea' in a new series in the same position otherwise it just copies over x to new series. It then assigns the new series with 'South Korea' back to the Country column.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah thats what i would have tried if I had only one condition but here I have multiple name changes

Comment: if your needs are only name changes then yes. But you can do a lot of things with map if what you need is: "How to change the column values in pandas based on some condition". You could even set values of a column based on a condition on another column. e.g. if Energy_Supply_per_Capita < 10 set Country to "Energy poor country" or something.